# Swift Core Data - Change location of persistent store

Tags: swift, core-data, nspersistentcontainer

I have a swift program that reads CSV files and saves the data to a core data persistent store.  I would like to change the location of the persistent store.  Per Apple documentation it appears that I should be able to do so by overriding the default  directory in a sub class of NSPersistentContainer.  Below is my unsuccessful attempt.  The Xcode error is "cannot call value of non-function type URL".

```
final class CoreDataContainer: NSPersistentContainer {
    let storePathURL: URL = URL(string: "file:///Users/Chris/Developer/Persistent Store")!
    override class func defaultDirectoryURL() -> URL {
        return super.defaultDirectoryURL()
            .absoluteURL(storePathURL)
   }
}
```

Comment: you're trying to chain `absoluteURL(storePathURL)` to the output of `super.defaultDirectoryURL()` but `absoluteURL(storePathURL)` is a URL not a method that can process the URL provided by the parent class.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are asking:

```
let storePathURL = // ...
let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: storePathURL)
let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "YourAppName")

container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]

container.loadPersistentStores { _, error in
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Have changed my Core Data Manager accordingly.  The line "let storePathURL: URL = URL(string: "/Users/Chris/Developer/Persistent Store/")! fails.  Says it found a nil when unwrapping.  What have I done wrong.

Comment: Does `/Users/Chris/Developer/Persistent Store/` exist on your Mac?

Comment: Yes.  Tested if in a terminal window.  I changed the line to "let storePathURL: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/Chris/Developer/Persistent Store/", isDirectory: true)" and the line does not fail.  Now load persistent store fails.  I think it is a sandbox issue i.e. file access not allowed.  Not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the input.  I moved my folder into Downloads and added read/write access to it in the sandbox.  Below is the updated code that works.

```
class CoreDataManager: ObservableObject {
    let persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer
    static let shared = CoreDataManager()
    private init() {
        let storePathURL: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/Chris/Downloads/Persistent Store/Index Funds", isDirectory: false)
        let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: storePathURL)
        persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Index Funds")
        persistentContainer.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]
        persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores{ description, error in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Unable to initialize Core Data \(error)")
            }
        }
    } // end init
}
```

Comment: Good to see it is working. Please consider upvoting my answer since it helped you in finding a solution.